# Batch findstr regular expression to grep an item from a single line

Tags: regex, batch-file, for-loop, substitution, findstr

How can I use Microsoft findstr to "grep" an item from a single line?

I've got a line that goes something like this:

```
<config>test</config><item>some data</item><date>2007-11-02</date><datestart>2007-10-31</datestart><path>d:\test\test\test.txt</path>
```

Now if I want to grep the content inside of `<date>` and `</date>` how would I write that regular expression?

One thing to note is that I will have to take the findstr command into a for-loop in order to grep the date and store it in a variable.

example:

```
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%i in ('findstr /r /c:"regex" file.txt') do (
    set date=%%i
    set date=!date:-=!
)
```

Also, I don't want to rely on tokens as they may vary.

Comment: I think this problem can not be solved with `findstr`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use a trick to do what you want: after read the line in a variable, change `<date>` and `</date>` by a delimiter character that is not in the line (for example, `$`); then, just use a `for /F "tokens=2 delims=$"` to get the contents inside.

```
set /P the_line=< file.txt
set the_line=!the_line:^<date^>=$!
set the_line=!the_line:^</date^>=$!
for /F "tokens=2 delims=$" %%i in ("!the_line!") do set date=%%i
set date=%date:-=%
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. Would this however be possible:
If I want to replace the date with a new date:
`set /p the_line=< file.txt`
`set the_line=!the_line:%date%=%newdate%!`
`echo !the_line! > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex `"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]"` which should match your date.

Comment: Will it only return that specific string from that line? The problem I'm having is that the whole line gets returned.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure about findstr. grep -o <Pattern> would do this.